# How to give access to External users in salesforce

Tags: chatter, profile, permissions

Need to configure external Users in salesforce.

- External users should not have access to Chatter. they should not see the            chatter feeds.
- They should have access to only one app with limited permissions
- Updating records.

Can a new profile be created for this./Can a standard profile be cloned and modified - I tried cloning Force.com one app users and read only profile but even then i am unable to restrict the access to Chatter.

- There is a feature from salesforce that allows to Enable/Disable chatter for a User. But then I am thinking of which profile to use for the users
- I could see community user profiles that again needs additional Licences.

Can you pls reply with What is the Best way to achive the above requirement?

Comment: You can try this option to do that http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_chatter_pbr_pilot.htm

Comment: This is at profile or permissionset level only... This is the statement that you can see in the above link "your administrator can turn on Chatter for only the users that have been assigned the required user profile or permission sets"

Comment: Without using that pilot feature, can this be done by restricting access to "Chatter", "Chatter Instances" and any other objects that the chatter uses

Comment: Thats why this new solution actually came in to the picture... As of now you can't do this at profile level...

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, but as discussed in the comments only with this feature

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_chatter_pbr_pilot.htm

It must be enabled by support and therefore you have to log a ticket and answer some questions.

Once activated I can confirm that it worked for me as expected on two different Orgs. Also I had no negative side effects and I think you can use it without concerns.